# Reading input using format string in python

Tags: python, input, scanf

Suppose I want to read a sequence of inputs, where each input is a tuple is of the form `<string> , <integer>, <string>`. Additionally, there can be arbitrary amount of whitespace around the commas. An easy way to do this in C/C++ is to use `scanf` with format string `"%s , %d , %s"`. What is the equivalent function in python?

Suppose we knew that each input is on a separate line, then you could easily parse this in python using `split` and `strip`. But the newline requirement complicates things. Furthermore, we could even have weird inputs such as

`<s11>,    <i1>
    , <s12>      <s21>,
<i2>       , <s22>`

Where `s11, i1, s12` is the first input and `s21, i2, s22` is the second. And scanf would still be able to handle this. How does one do it in python? I also don't want to take the entire input at once and parse it, since I know that there will be other inputs that don't fit this format later on, and I don't want to do the parsing manually.

Comment: so there is no comma in between <s12> and <s21>?

Comment: @onno That's correct. But there can be arbitrary amount of whitespace there too (including newline(s)).

Comment: You are attributing way too much power to `scanf`. The problems you list also appear when (mis)using `scanf`. As there is no such function in Python, you indeed have to write one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to first strip the whitespace, then split on commas, then handle the resulting strings and integers however you want. The regular expression `s\+` matches any nonzero amount of whitespace characters:

```
input_string = "    hello     \n  \t   ,    10  ,   world   \n     "
stripped_string = re.sub('\s+', '', input_string)
substrings = stripped_string.split(',')
string1 = substrings[0]
integer1 = int(substrings[1])
string2 = substrings[2]
```

You'd just have to put those last three lines inside a loop if you need to handle multiple s,i,s tuples in a row.

EDIT: I realize now you want to interpret any whitespace *as* a comma. I'm not sure how wise that is, but a hacky way to do it is to replace all the commas with whitespace, split on whitespace, and call it a day

```
input_string = "    hello     \n  \t   ,    10     world   \n     "
stripped_string = re.sub(',', ' ', input_string)
substrings = stripped_string.split()
string1 = substrings[0]
integer1 = int(substrings[1])
string2 = substrings[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

For delimited format it's pretty easy with the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) module.
You can plugin any kind of [file-like inputs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) to it.

And you handle stripping white spaces and type casting downstream. Here's a sample to get you going:

```
In [25]: import fileinput

In [26]: import csv

In [28]: reader = csv.reader(fileinput.input())

In [29]: for l in reader:
    ...:     print(l)
    ...:
stdin input -> a,b, c, d
print output -> ['a', 'b', ' c', ' d   ']
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple equivalent could be as follows (results are returned as strings):

```
def scan(s, fmt) :
  result = []

  ind = 0; # s upto ind has been consumed
  slen = len(s)

  i = 0
  while i < len(fmt) :  
    c = fmt[i] 
    if c == "%" and i < len(fmt) - 1 : 
      d = fmt[i+1] 
      if d == "s" : 
        endstring = s[ind:slen].find(" ") 
        if endstring == -1 : 
          result.append(s[ind:slen])
          return result 
        else : 
          result.append(s[ind:(ind+endstring)])
          ind = ind + endstring
        i = i + 1  
      else : 
        if d == "d" : 
          inchars = "" 
          for j in range(ind, slen) : 
            x = s[j] 
            if x.isdecimal() :
              inchars = inchars + x
            else : 
              break
          result.append(inchars)
          ind = ind + len(inchars)
          i = i + 1
        else : 
          if d == "f" : 
            incharsf = "" 
            for j in range(ind, slen) : 
              y = s[j] 
              if y.isdecimal() or y == "." :
                incharsf = incharsf + y
              else : 
                break
            result.append(incharsf)
            ind = ind + len(incharsf)
            i = i + 1
    else :
      if s[ind] == c :  
        ind = ind+1 
      else :  
        return result
    i = i + 1
  return result 


print(StringLib.scan("30=100.5#45", "%d=%f#%d"))
```